# Можно ли вместо доменного имени писать ip? И как?

Tags: url, ip, домен

Можно ли, например, вместо `google.com` или других имен писать `1.255.90.xx...(ip ненастоящий)`  и др. ?

**Если да**, *то как узнать ip-адрес сайта* **?**

**Если нет**, *то почему* **?**

Comment: Можно, берите любой IP-адрес и пишите: [http://185.125.217.231/](http://185.125.217.231/)

Comment: @andreymal А как мне собственно узнать ip?(например, Гугла)

Comment: Отправить DNS-запрос любым способом и получить его результат, самый «колхозный» — просто сделать ping в командной строке

Comment: Спасибо, попробую

Comment: 8.8.8.8 - Google. Один из ходовых адресов :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно. Но не всегда.

Отправляя http запрос на `http://ip-address/uri` на сервер приходит запрос с заголовком `Host: ip-address`.
Если при этом http-сервер настроен на выдачу хоста «по умолчанию», вы получите данные с этого ресурса.

Не стоит забывать, однако, что на одном сервере может обслуживаться множество виртуальных хостов. Все они слушают один интерфейс. К какому именно вы попадёте, сервер определяет по домену из заголовка `Host`.

---

> А как мне собственно узнать ip?(например, Гугла)

Для этого существуют специальные протоколы DNS. И утилиты, работающие с этими протоколами(`nslookup`, `drill` и т.п.).

Большие сайты, привязывают к домену сразу несколько IP адресов и резольвят их по технологии round-robin(с каждым запросом первым в списке будет другой IP). Некоторые также раздают разные пулы IP, в зависимости от местонахождения клиента.

> ```
> $ drill google.com
> ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, rcode: NOERROR, id: 4719
> ;; flags: qr rd ra ; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 6, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0 
> ;; QUESTION SECTION:
> ;; google.com.    IN  A
>
> ;; ANSWER SECTION:
> google.com.   1   IN  A   74.125.131.113
> google.com.   1   IN  A   74.125.131.102
> google.com.   1   IN  A   74.125.131.139
> google.com.   1   IN  A   74.125.131.100
> google.com.   1   IN  A   74.125.131.138
> google.com.   1   IN  A   74.125.131.101
>
> ;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
>
> ;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
>
> ;; Query time: 64 msec
> ;; SERVER: 8.8.4.4
> ;; WHEN: Thu Jun 27 21:55:43 2019
> ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 124
> ```

---

> 1.808.5789.908

IP четвёртой версии - это 4 байта информации. Для удобства восприятия, распространён формат, в котором эти 4 байта представлены по отдельности с разделителем-точкой. Из-за этого, числа в составе IPv4 адреса никогда не бывают больше 255.
Также, это не единственный способ представить IP адрес.

Например, можно поразрядно сложить эти байты и пользоваться одним большим числом, например, для IP 74.125.131.102:

> ```
> >>> (((((74 << 8) + 125) << 8) + 131) << 8) + 102
> 1249739622
> ```

абсолютно валидной будет ссылка http://1249739622/

Comment: *можно поразрядно сложить эти байты и пользоваться одним большим числом* - как-то я про это призабыл, большое спасибо за развернутый ответ. (+)

Answer (score 2):

1. Да, по идее можно: http://64.233.161.94 (ip настоящий - у меня сейчас в него ресолвится гугл). Но есть несколько нюансов, почему подобное может не рботать:

   - сайт может сам проверять host и не реагировать на ip-адрес вместо имени
   - на одном ip может существовать несколько сайтов, выбор между которыми происходит на основе host'а. В таком случае сервер либо выдаст ошибку, либо покажет страницу хостинга-владельца.
   - при использовании защищённых протоколов (https) сертификат выдан на доменное имя, а не на ip-адрес, а значит браузер признает сертификат невалидным.
2. Тут можно рассказать кучу всего про dns, но я обычно просто делаю в консоли ping:

   ```
   C:\>ping google.ru

   Pinging google.ru [64.233.161.94] with 32 bytes of data:
   Reply from 64.233.161.94: bytes=32 time=37ms TTL=48
   Reply from 64.233.161.94: bytes=32 time=44ms TTL=48
   Reply from 64.233.161.94: bytes=32 time=37ms TTL=48
   Reply from 64.233.161.94: bytes=32 time=37ms TTL=48

   Ping statistics for 64.233.161.94:
       Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
   Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
       Minimum = 37ms, Maximum = 44ms, Average = 38ms
   ```