# xhr.open IP адрес

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Можно ли как-то использовать в запросе вместо url айпи адрес?
xhr2.open('POST', '*здесь айпишник*/Server/load.php', true);
возвращает 404, хотя на локалке все работает.

Comment: должно работать =)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ но не обязано :)

Comment: [Можно-ли вместо доменного имени писать ip? И как?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/997120/221228)